# Can an ObjectDataSource have more than 1 sort expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can an `ObjectDataSource` have multiple `SortExpression's`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can have only 1 sort expression at any given time, but you can sort on multiple fields:

> .Sort = "column1 asc, column2 asc"

Comment: If possible, could you provide an example.  Thanks!

Comment: I really wish I could find documentation indicating what order I should apply those sort parameters.  I guess I'll just try, 50% chance of being right.

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly answer your question I tend to do all presorting on my physical objects before binding them to anything taking advantage of List<>.Sort or LINQ .OrderBy other than that I will leave all sorting up to the client side like using JQuery to sort the physical html table.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you would sort an asp:ListBox with an asp:Drodown using JQuery.

Comment: Like what would be in the drop down, ascending/descending or something else?